# Get the Ip Info from Client to Web Api

Tags: angularjs, security, asp.net-web-api, ip

fist at all sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to get the IP in the login option to save them as a "Session" in the database and register who and where is using the app.

I try this, but it obvious that it isn't going to work.

```
var ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://ipinfo.io/json");
```

It Gets the IP Client. So it logical that I need to do this get in the Client side. But the problem is that the Client can change this values before its send to the Web API

```
$http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json").then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
}).catch(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data);
});
```

The users can change this value to send me a false data in the login and I don't have how to validate if this information is valid or real. So, the question is ¿How can I do this without let the user manipulate this data?

Comment: Instead of requesting http://ipinfo.io/json on the server you should request http://ipinfo.io/<client ip>/json as per https://ipinfo.io/developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in web API, and we can save all the information needed directly to database.

```
   public static string UserIp()
        {
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }

            try
            {
                string url1 = "http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/" + ip.ToString(); // passing IP address will return location information. 
                WebClient client = new WebClient(); // Intialize the webclient 
                string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url1);
                dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring); // De-serialize the JSON string
                string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\App_Data\\Logs\\" + "Ip.txt";
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
// you can save the information to database instead of writing to a file 

                    writer.WriteLine("UserIp:" + ip);
                    writer.WriteLine("Date:" + DateTime.Now);
                    writer.WriteLine("JsonString:" + jsonstring);
                    writer.WriteLine("Country name:" + dynObj.country.code);

                }

                return dynObj;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\App_Data\\Logs\\" + "I.txt";
                string url1 = "http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/" + ip.ToString();
                WebClient client = new WebClient(); // Intialize the webclient 
                string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url1);
                dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
                //  string a = dynObj.country.code;
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" +
                                     ex.StackTrace +
                                     "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                    writer.WriteLine("UserIp:" + ip);
                    writer.WriteLine("Dynamic obj:" + dynObj);
                }
                return null;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Is normal that in Local test get in string ip = "::1"?

Comment: I didn't get you what you are trying to say ?

Comment: This HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; get me null.
This HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; get me "::1" as value.

Comment: if you are debugging, you are most likely requesting on local host.  I recommend you to create a website on IIS server and point towards your project directory. Then try to debug it. Then you should see ip "127.0.0.1"
Use this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/) on how to host web-api on IIS server